# Est-il possible (souhaitable ?) d'envoyer un message personnel à un autre membre ?

Tags: support, user-interface

Tout est dans le titre, ou presque. J'entends par là : pour éviter de polluer l'une des questions/réponses avec des commentaires hors-sujet.

Je n'ai pas trouvé cette option dans l'interface, et je me suis demandé si c'était :

1) moi qui ne sait pas me servir de mes yeux mais l'option existe quelque part (ce qui est très possible)

2) l'option qui n'existe techniquement pas encore sur le site (ce qui serait assez surprenant mais sait-on jamais)

3) un choix délibéré pour une raison qui m'échappe (ce qui me semble assez probable, mais auquel cas je serais intéressé de connaître les raisons qui motivent ce choix)

Comment: En anglais sur le Meta global: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users

Comment: OK merci Stéphane, je n'avais pas pensé à regarder là-bas directement en effet. Je suis déçu mais... au moins j'ai ma réponse !

Comment: @RomainVALERI [Pas tout à fait privé mais quand même pas public](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15436630#15436630) !

Comment: @Laure Oui, merci de l'idée, c'est vrai que je n'ai jamais mis les pieds sur le chat, mais ça aurait été une solution. Le point important ici pour moi étant plus la possibilité d'engager un "hors-sujet" sans polluer les Q&A, nettement moins le besoin de discrétion. Excellente alternative, donc.

Comment: En l'occurrence et pour la petite histoire, c'était en voyant Aerovistae dire qu'il était impatient de venir en France, je voulais lui dire quelque chose comme "Si tu passes en Lorraine tu es le bienvenu !". Ce qui, étant donné l'attractivité touristique de la région, est à peu près aussi probable que le mariage gay de Serge Dassault et David Douillet la semaine prochaine. Mais voilà ^^ (Heu... est-ce que je ne viens pas de commettre précisément le méfait que mon message a pour but d'éviter ? D'oh...)

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange n'est pas un réseau social. Le site est plus proche de Wikipedia que de Facebook. C'est tout à fait volontaire qu'il n'y a pas de moyen de communication privé entre les utilisateurs. (Il y a des moyens de communiquer en privé avec les modérateurs, en particulier via le *flag*, mais ce n'est pas à titre personnel que le modérateur participe alors. J'exclus les communications avec les modérateurs du champ de ma réponse.)

Il existe une interface de clavardage (*chat*). Chaque site sur Stack Exchange a au moins un salon de clavardage associé, certains en ont plusieurs suivant la thématique. Sur *French Language*, nous avons seulement notre salon principal, [*Chez Cosette*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1098/chez-cosette). Le clavardage est public et archivé indéfiniment (on peut donc sauter sur une conversation en cours).

La participation au clavardage est purement facultative. On peut notifier un autre utilisateur (avec la syntaxe `@nom`), mais seulement s'il a parlé dans le salon récemment. Si une série de commentaires semble se prolonger, on peut suggérer de continuer là-bas ; d'ailleurs le système le propose automatiquement dans certains cas (en créant un salon dédié).

Voir aussi [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users) sur le site méta principal, et la [FAQ du chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Le lien entre ma demande et les réseaux sociaux me parait ténue, je n'ai ni le besoin ni l'envie de 'tisser des liens' comme sur FaceBouc et consorts, je voulais simplement savoir comment poser à un utilisateur une question hors-sujet (mais ne me le réexpliquez pas s'il vous plait, j'ai compris que ce n'était pas le projet ici). Je ne pratique pas le chat non plus, donc je me passerai de communiquer de cette manière et m'en tiendrai autant que possible aux questions/réponses. *soupir*